# Taking ADHD medicine on Shabbos (ex: Adderall/ Ritalin)

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine, psych-mentalhealth

Following on the heels of recent questions "[Why restrict medicine on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104877/why-restrict-medicine-on-shabbat)?" & "[Is clinical depression medication allowed on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104862/is-someone-who-has-clinical-depression-allowed-to-take-an-antidepressant-on-shab)?"

- Is it permitted to take ADHD medicine such as Adderall/ Ritalin on Shabbos?
- Is ADHD considered a sufficient enough illness to warrant taking medicine on Shabbos?

Comment: I think leaving some info in about the short and long term consequences of skipping this medication would be helpful. (I'm not knowledgeable enough to edit that in)

Comment: Rav Ovadia Yosef also permits "pep" pills on shabbat. Ritalin is definitionally a pep pill, aimed at waking one up and enabling them to concentrate. He does add that it should be for the sake of enabling learning on Shabbat. I will try to find the reference when I get a chance.

Comment: Medically speaking, some doctors would say it's fine to take a drug holiday... but others say if you take it daily, you shouldn't stop.

Answer (score 4):

R [David Sperling](https://meirtv.com/en/rabbi-david-sperling--18r) ([here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6146)) writes it seems to him that taking these medicines is permitted because

> - Firstly, **someone who has started on a course of pills before Shabbat
>   may continue to take them even on Shabbat** (see Shmirat Shabbat
>   KeHilchatah, 34, 17).
> - Secondly, it is not clear that someone with ADHD
>   is considered at all "sick" or "under the weather". See for example
>   Shmirat Shabbat KeHilchatah (ibid 19) that birth control pills are not
>   forbidden, and the footnote there (in the Hebrew edition) explains
>   that **only cases where someone is in physical pain or weakness is
>   forbidden to take medicines**. It could be that they have the law of a
>   healthy person, in which case the taking of medicines is the subject
>   of debate (see the Shulchan Aruch ibid, 37, and the Mishna Brurah
>   120). Even those generally strict on this question (ie. the
>   Ashkenazim) could take the lenient opinion as an extra reason for
>   leniency, together with the other reasons I cite.
> - Thirdly, **the
>   medicines for ADHD that exist today do not cure the condition - they
>   merely treat the symptoms of hyperactivity and lack of ability to
>   concentrate. It would seem that the Rabbis only forbade medicines that
>   bring about a cure**. (See Yalkut Yosef 328,52). Lastly, there is much
>   discussion about the extent to which this rabbinic decree is still in
>   force today when the underlying reasoning for it (ie that one may be
>   led to grind the plants to make the medicine) does not seem to apply
>   any more. (See the Tzitz Eliezer, volume 8, 15, 15 for a lengthy
>   discussion of this issue). Even though all the modern day poskim hold
>   that we do apply this decree, there is room to take the lenient
>   rulings together with long-term medications such as in the case of
>   ADHD.

As a followup, I have now explicitly seen in R Avrohom Yaged's [guide to refuah on Shabbos](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422638224.html) that he writes (p. 62 and also p. 84)

> A person who has been diagnosed with ADD or ADHD may take medicine for
> it, even though he is not actually sick. Because he cannot function
> normally without his medicine, he is considered a *choleh* in this
> regard.

As @Shokhet mentioned in comments, it's very important idea to ask a knowledgeable rabbi for guidance in real cases. Individual circumstances differ greatly, and (especially with regard to psychiatric medication) what is optional for one person may be life-or-death for another (with obvious implications for issues surrounding Shabbos).